# Discord .NET Value of type EmbedBuilder cannot be converted to Embed

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

As the title says i get "Value of type EmbedBuilder cannot be converted to Embed" error.
This is the code i'm trying right now :

```
               If msg.Equals("gDurum") Then

                Dim eb As New EmbedBuilder With {
            .Title = "Sunucu Bilgisi",
            .Color = New Color(255, 0, 0),
            .ImageUrl = "https://cache.gametracker.com/server_info/185.198.73.27:27015/b_560_95_1.png",
            .Description = "Deneme"
            }
                eb.Build()

                Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, eb)
```

Comment: Compilation error or run-time exception? Where exactly is the error generated?

Comment: It's a compilation error.

1>C:\Users\Berke\source\repos\Discord Galaxy\Discord Galaxy\Form1.vb(57,78): error BC30311: Value type 'EmbedBuilder' cannot be converted to 'Embed'

And it's generated in SendMessageAsync (eb) part.

Comment: So that would suggest that the third parameter of the `SendMessageAsync` method is type `Embed` and you are passing it `eb`, which is type `EnbedBuilder`. Presumably an `EnbedBuilder` builds an `Enbed` so you must get that `Enbed` from the `EmbedBuilder` in some way. My first guess would be that that `Build` method returns it.

Comment: I just checked the documentation for that `EmbedBuilder` class, which was the second result when I searched for "discord .net embedbuilder" (that is exactly what you should have done already) and it is indeed the case that `Build` returns an `Embed` object and that is what you would need to pass to `SendMessageAsync`.

Comment: When an `EmbedBuilder` is built, the type is built into a proper `Embed` ready to be sent and used as a rich embed. In this case, you are assigning a built `Embed` and forcing it to fit under an `EmbedBuilder`, which would not work. Simply change the type of `eb` to `Embed` would fix it.

Comment: I fixed it ! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the solution. I was trying to pass the EmbedBuilder instead of Embed.

Here's my new code :

```
 If msg.Equals("gDurum") Then



                Dim eb As New EmbedBuilder With {
            .Title = "Sunucu Bilgisi",
            .Color = New Color(255, 0, 0),
            .ImageUrl = "https://cache.gametracker.com/server_info/185.198.73.27:27015/b_560_95_1.png",
            .Description = "Deneme"
            }

                Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, eb.Build())
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking at [the official code example](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html) might encounter [type mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVPfZ.png) while compiling.

**Make sure to build Discord.Embed into a Rich Embed which is ready to be sent.**

Corrected & working code example for this:

```
[Command("embed")]
public async Task SendRichEmbedAsync()
{
    var embed = new EmbedBuilder
        {
            // Embed property can be set within object initializer
            Title = "Hello world!"
            Description = "I am a description set by initializer."
        };
        // Or with methods
    embed.AddField("Field title",
        "Field value. I also support [hyperlink markdown](https://example.com)!")
        .WithAuthor(Context.Client.CurrentUser)
        .WithFooter(footer => footer.Text = "I am a footer.")
        .WithColor(Color.Blue)
        .WithTitle("I overwrote \"Hello world!\"")
        .WithDescription("I am a description.")
        .WithUrl("https://example.com")
        .WithCurrentTimestamp();
    await ReplyAsync(embed: embed.Build());
}
```